# Convert array of Model into an array of the specified Model.attribute

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

```
cars = Car.find(data).find_all{ |car| car.model == "Honda" }
```

this returns a list of Car's--I'd like to convert this list to a list that only contains the car.id's. How would I do it in a Ruby like way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simply call:

```
cars = Car.find(data).find_all{ |car| car.model == "Honda" }.map{ |car| car.id }
```

http://corelib.rubyonrails.org/classes/Array.html#M000427

Answer (score 2):

You can do this:

```
car_ids = Car.find(data).find_all{ |car| car.model=="Honda" }.map{ |car| car.id }
```

Essentially, `array.map { |x| f(x) }` returns a new array of identical size, which contains the result of calling `f` on each of the original array's entries, in the same order.

Answer (score 1):

I'd do it like that:

```
cars = Car.where(id: data, model: 'Honda').pluck(:id)
```

assuming that `data` is an array of car id's